Meaning of adding planes represented in the same basis
According to "Clifford algebra of points, lines and planes" by Selig, a plane can be described by a unit normal vector $\boldsymbol{n}$ and a perpendicular distance $d=\boldsymbol{r} \cdot \boldsymbol{n}$ from the origin of a frame where $\boldsymbol{r}$ any point in the plane shown as follows
$\hspace{6cm}$ 
Let $\boldsymbol{n}_{1,2} = \hat{\imath}$ and $\boldsymbol{r}_1 = 2\hat{\imath}$ and $\boldsymbol{r}_2 = 3\hat{\imath}$, the planes are
$$
\begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{\pi}_1 &= \boldsymbol{n}_1 + e d_1, \\
\boldsymbol{\pi}_2 &= \boldsymbol{n}_2 + e d_2
\end{aligned}
$$
My question is what is the interpretation of $\boldsymbol{\pi}_1+\boldsymbol{\pi}_2$? When I add them, the yielded normal axis from the addition has no unit norm. Specifically,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{\pi}_3 &= \boldsymbol{\pi}_1 + \boldsymbol{\pi}_2, \\
 &= 2\hat{\imath} + e 5.
\end{aligned}
$$
The distance $d_3$ makes sense; however, $\| \boldsymbol{n}_3 \| \neq 1$. In addition, if $\boldsymbol{n}_1 = \hat{\imath}$ and $\boldsymbol{n}_2 = -\hat{\imath}$, $\boldsymbol{n}_3 = 0$ which makes no sense.

This paper by Selig is a sort of bastardardized (or perhaps simply early) account of Plane-based/Projective Geometric Algebra (PGA). Good introductions are this video by YouTuber sudgylacmoe and this series of videos by Leo Dorst and Steven De Keninck on the "Bivector" YouTube channel. Dorst and De Keninck also have written May the Forque Be with You, which has some more physics-oriented content (though I have one small complaint that they "improperly" represent directions using vectors in the algebra rather than "properly" using ideal trivectors).
PGA is inherently projective. This means two things:

Geometric objects are represented in the algebra not by values but by values up to a multiple. So if $a\ne0$ is a scalar and $\pi$ represents a plane then $\alpha\pi$ is the same plane; we could also say that the values are oriented and weighted versions of the corresponding geometric objects. This also means that we have to normalize to get geometric quantities out of these values; for instance, if $P, Q$ represent points then $$\sqrt{\left|\frac{(P\vee Q)^2}{P^2Q^2}\right|}$$ is the distance between them, with $P^2$ and $Q^2$ essentially being the weights of each point.

There are ideal elements, also called elements at infinity. In your notation, $e$ (or rather it together with all its multiples) represents the plane at infinity. There are also lines at infinity and points at infinity, which respectively can be used to represent free planes and directions.


It is best to abandon the notion that you are working with "normal vectors". Instead, we can think of addition of planes as follows:

Let $p_1, p_2$ be (weighted, oriented, potentially ideal) planes. They are guaranteed to have an line of intersection because this is projective geometry. (If they're parallel, then it's an ideal line at infinity.) The sum $p' = p_1 + p_2$ is then also a plane containing the same line which is inbetween $p_1$ and $p_2$ and is closer to the plane of highest weight.

Here is how this idea works out more concretely:

If both planes are nonideal but not parallel, $\theta$ is the angle between them, and $|p_1| = \sqrt{|p_1^2|}$ and $|p_2| = \sqrt{|p_2^2|}$ are their weights, then more concretely $$\cos\theta_1' = p_1^2 + p_2\cdot p_1 = |p_1|^2 + |p_1||p_2|\cos\theta,\quad \cos\theta_2' = p_2^2 + p_1\cdot p_2 = |p_2|^2 + |p_1||p_2|\cos\theta$$ with $\theta_1',\theta_2'$ the angles between $p'$ and $p_1,p_2$.

If one of $p_1, p_2$ is ideal (say $p_2$), then $p'$ is parallel to $p_1$ since they must contain the same ideal line. The higher $p_2$ is weighted, the further away $p'$ will be from $p_1$. The precise distance is $$\frac{|p_2|_\infty}{|p_1|} $$ where $|p_2|_\infty$ can be defined by $$|p_2|_\infty = \frac{|{\oslash}\vee p_2|}{|{\oslash}|}$$ for any nonideal point $\oslash$. (It is independent of the point chosen.)

When $p_1, p_2$ are both nonideal but are parallel, then $p'$ is a parallel plane between them when they have the same orientation, and is instead a parallel plane "outside" of them when they have opposite orientations. The distance of $p'$ from $p_1$ is precisely $$ \frac{|p_1\wedge p_2|_\infty}{|p_1||p_1+p_2|}. $$ In the particular case that $p_1,p_2$ have the same weight but opposite orientations, $p'$ is the plane at infinity; it is "equally outside" of both of them.


